# how to use one database in several python file

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I working on a project and I want to use one database in two python file
but, when I run every project they created database for self
if you know please tell me how I can use that

```py
import sqlite3


def connect():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("waiters.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
       "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS salary (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , name text, age INTEGER , price INTEGER )"
    )
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


def insert(name, age, price):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("waiters.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "INSERT INTO salary VALUES (NULL ,?,?,?)", (name ,age ,price)
    )
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def view():
    conn = sqlite3.connect("waiters.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM salary"
    )
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

def search(name="", age="", price=""):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("waiters.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "SELECT * FROM salary WHERE name = ? OR age = ? OR price = ?", (name, age, price)
    )
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return rows

def delete(id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("waiters.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM salary WHERE id=?", (id,))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def update(id, name, age, price):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("waiters.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "UPDATE salary SET name = ?, age = ?, price = ? WHERE id = ?", (name, age, price, id)
    )
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def update_pay_money(name, price):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("waiters.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        "UPDATE salary SET price = ?  WHERE name = ?", (price, name)
    )
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()


connect()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40M4t.jpg)

Comment: Try something like `conn = sqlite3.connect("../waiters.db")`

Answer (score 2):

Giving exact path like `/path/to/waiters.db` while connecting to your database should solve your problem?

This line should be changed while connecting to database.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("/path/to/waiters.db")
```

Comment: @mobinbagheri you haven't marked this answer as accepted answer, hasn't this helped you to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

as Other mentioned for using a sqllite3 db in multiple files you can use their absolute or relative path, for example if you have 'DBs' & 'section-1' & 'section-2' directories and your python file are in section directories you can access the database file in each section by using somthing like this '"../DBs/waiters.db"' and so on for others... but whatf of you try make multiple tables in a database file in tgat way you don need to have multiple databases and its the standard way,
hope it's help